# iOS Slider touchesEnded Parameters

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a slider element that I want to detect a touchesEnded action on.

I'm trying to add the touchesEnded action programmatically:

```
[self.slider touchesEnded:(NSSet *] touches withEvent:event];
```

The problem is I have no idea where to get the touches variable from (I'm assuming the event param is the function I wish to call after the touch has ended).

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass for UISlider. Implement

`- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

method in the sub-class. Delegate the touch event to your view.

Comment: How will my implementation work then though? I imagine in the CustomUISlider.m file I will have the touchesEnded method but this will be unable to access the NSTimer object that I am using in my view controller.

Comment: Use delegate and protocol. Once touch ended, delegate the event to the view controller with the `touches` object.